# React Angular Wordpress Multisite WP-API - SEO?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, reactjs, seo, wp-api

Hi I am attempting to build a largish website for my company & love to get some feedback on whether I am crazy or its a great idea. I am basically got the ok to go free rein, I guess as long as its going to have benefits (e.g performance, maintainability, scalability, re usability & SEO)

The way I am thinking of going about it.

- Wordpress multisite (company has a handful of branches worldwide) e.g China, South Africa, US etc, so content needs to be tailored. Plan to use subdomains?
- WP REST API - ability for reusable data across the websites and other blogging sites (scalability and performance) also the capability of browsing offline? http://themeshaper.com/tag/react/
- AngularJS for routing/views/get-post requests or possibly React-router?
- ReactJS for the view (performance and reusable components across all sites)
- Most importantly - good for SEO (site is crawlable) which I believe ReactJS has that covered? ref: http://en.blog.altima.fr/seo/reactjs-seo/ but also whether I need prerender.io or other because of the routing?

Wondering how this will all work together and if theres any issues with the combination of these? Still also getting my head around if this needs to be setup as "Isomorphic" with a node server? (some more insight into this would be great also)

I have been inspired by the theme https://github.com/royboy789/angular-react-wordpress-theme

Thanks!

Comment: there is no ready made solution for SEO yet, if you need all those technology. more technology, harder to render at server side. and yes all those universal (isomorphic) solution need nodejs for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that mix of cool buzzwords (WP, Angular, React) is the good way to choose you technology stack. May be good ideas is to use Angular+Laravel, React+Laravel, Wp+HTML.

Considering SEO if you use Angular or React you just have AJAX-site. You can use prerender technique for your site. But recently Google stated that AJAX-crawl scheme is deprecated: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html . So may be there is no need to prerender your pages only for crawlers.